# Why do all elements commute in centre of an arbitrary finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups

The section below is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)):

> The center of G is always a [subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) of G. In particular:
>
> 1.
>   $Z(G)$ contains the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of $G$, $e$, because, for all $g \in G$, it commutes with $g$, $eg = g = ge$, by definition;
>
> 2.
>   If $x$ and $y$ are in $Z(G)$, then so is $xy$, by associativity: $(xy)g = x(yg) = x(gy) = (xg)y = (gx)y = g(xy)$ for each $g \in G$; i.e., $Z(G)$ is closed;
>
> 3.
>   If $x$ is in $Z(G)$, then so is $x^{−1}$ as, for all $g$ in $G$, $x^{−1}$ commutes with $g$: $(gx = xg) \implies (x^{−1}gxx^{−1} = x^{−1}xgx^{−1}) \implies (x^{−1}g = gx^{−1})$.
>   Furthermore, the center of $G$ is always a [normal subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) of $G$, as it is closed under [conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_closure), as all elements commute.

I do not understand the last bit, why do all elements commute in $Z(G)$?

My attemt was to try to get $ab=ba$:
$a,b \in Z(G) \implies \exists g,ga=ag, gb=bg\implies gagb=agbg$, but this doesnt't seem to lead anywhere useful.

Comment: Apply $g=b$.....

Comment: Your "$\exists$" should be a "$\forall$."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elements in the centre of a group, by definition, commute with all elements of the group $G$. Therefore they certainly commute with eachother.

Specifically, $Z(G) := \{ z \in G | zg = gz \; \forall g \in G\}$. If you have $a,b \in Z(G)$, then putting $a$ and $b$ into the definition above gives you what you want, right?

Comment: In my notes I have this: centre $Z$ is defined
to be the set of elements which each form their own conjugacy class. From here, is it obvious that they commute with each other? I think what this means that there is at least one element in $G$ with which they commute. Why can we say that "they commute with all", not "at least one"?

Comment: Looking at your edit... I dont get why is it $Z(G) := \{ z \in G | zg = gz \; \forall g \in G\}$ and not $Z(G) := \{ z \in G | zg = gz \; \exists g \in G\}$

Comment: If an element $x \in G$ forms its own conjugacy class, then you have that $\{gxg^{-1} | g \in G\} = \{x\}$. In particular, $gxg^{-1} = x \; \forall g \in G$. Thus, if $x \in Z(G)$, $gx = xg$ for all $g \in G$. My alternative definition then drops out, and things follow. Your assertion that "there is at least one element in $G$ with which they commute" is not quite correct, although it is understandable why you're confused. I think the definition which I give above of the centre of a group is a little easier for less experienced people to understand.

Comment: Additionally: It is worth you knowing that not only does your definition imply mine, but mine implies yours. They're *equivalent*. I've given you one implication, and you should see if you can get the reverse implication too.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [@Matt's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2925515/590567). The key step helping me to understand both the Q and that answer:

Two group elements $g_1, g_2 \in G$ are conjugate to each other ($g_1 \sim g_2$) if there exists any group element $g \in G$ s.t.

$g_2 = gg_1g^{−1}$.

Now, if $g_1$ is its own conjugacy class, then $gg_1g^{−1}$ has always has to give $g_1$ for any $g$ because if it does not, then $g_1$ would be in the same conjugacy class as the result of $gg_1g^{−1}$, so for any $g$, we have $gg_1=g_1g$, if $g_1$ forms its own conjugacy class.